# Android RxJava2 - Adding subscription to CompositeDisposable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an Observable and PublishSubject and they are subscribed.
I tried using subscribe and subscribeWith both did not work because of incompatible types. Could you suggest, how can I add this subscription to CompositeDisposable?

```
public Observable getObservable() {
  //returns Observable object;
}

PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();

CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

// The below statement gives error: requiredtype Disposable but provided void. 
disposable.add(getObservable().subscribe(subject));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
disposable.add(getObservable().subscribe(yourObject -> {
    subject.onNext(yourObject);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
    Disposable d = getObservable().subscribe(
            subject::onNext,
            subject::onError,
            subject::onComplete
    );
    disposable.add(d);
```

Just remember to dispose publisher's subscriptions and you will be fine.